# What was the first ever P2WSH transaction?

Tags: p2wsh

I've managed to find the first-ever segwit transaction, which is also the first-ever P2WPKH transaction:

[dfcec48bb8491856c353306ab5febeb7e99e4d783eedf3de98f3ee0812b92bad](https://mempool.space/tx/dfcec48bb8491856c353306ab5febeb7e99e4d783eedf3de98f3ee0812b92bad)

However I'm having trouble finding the first-ever P2WSH transaction. Help appreciated!!

Comment: I just learned I can search for this myself using Blockchair. I will update when I find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, using Blockchair as a free and easy search tool.

The first transaction sent to a P2WSH address is this one:

[461e8a4aa0a0e75c06602c505bd7aa06e7116ba5cd98fd6e046e8cbeb00379d6](https://mempool.space/tx/461e8a4aa0a0e75c06602c505bd7aa06e7116ba5cd98fd6e046e8cbeb00379d6)

It occurred in the same block as the first P2WPKH transaction.

At the time of writing, it still has not been spent.

The first transaction that has spent funds from P2WSH is this one:

[cab75da6d7fe1531c881d4efdb4826410a2604aa9e6442ab12a08363f34fb408](https://mempool.space/tx/cab75da6d7fe1531c881d4efdb4826410a2604aa9e6442ab12a08363f34fb408)

It occurred a couple days later.